# Checkbox will not stay checked with the data-bind in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have a checkbox that I want to execute a function when it is clicked. The issue is, it needs to execute a different function based on whether or not the checkbox is checked.  So, I setup a status observable that is set to false by default:

```
self.status = ko.observable(false);
```

I binded a function to the checkbox on click:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: modify, checked: status">
```

And I created the function to execute a different function based on whether or not the status observable is true or false:

```
self.modify = function() {
    if (self.status() == false) {
        // Some other code
        alert('Now True!')
        self.status(true);
    }
    else if (self.status() == true) {
        // Some other code
        alert('Now False!');
        self.status(false)
    }
}
```

This function works perfectly fine. It alerts the correct message based on whether or not status is true or false, however the issue is, I cannot seem to get the checkbox to stay checked when the status is true.

http://jsfiddle.net/tsnolan23/s441hggL/

Any ideas on why the checkbox is not staying checked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

1. You click the checkbox.
2. The click handler fires, it sets `status`.
3. The checked handler fires, it changes the checkbox status.
4. The event bubbles to the browser, which reverts the change.
5. Knockout notices this, and updates `status` again.

Here's a whole different approach, using writeable computeds for this purpose:

```js
var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  var _isActive = ko.observable(false);
  self.isActive = ko.computed({
    read: _isActive,
    write: function(newValue) {
      _isActive(newValue);
      if (!!newValue) { alert("Something..."); }
      else { alert("Another thing."); }
    }
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isActive" /> Check me!
</label>
```

If you *must* for some reason use the `click` binding, then you should do two things:

- `return true` from your handler
- set `clickBubble: false` on the bindings

For example:

```js
var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.isActive = ko.observable(false);
  
  self.modify = function() {
    if (self.isActive() == false) {
      // Some other code
      alert('Now True!')
    }
    else if (self.isActive() == true) {
      // Some other code
      alert('Now False!');
    }
    
    return true;
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: modify, clickBubble: false, checked: isActive" /> Check me!
</label>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

Comment: I just used your initial code without the clickbubble, and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much, and you're right, I also needed it to work when the label is clicked as well!

Comment: Good to know it helped. I did remove the "label" bit from my answer though, to my surprise the `click` binding also fired if the `label`'s text was clicked. :D

Comment: I think there is no need to set `self.isActive(true)` or `self.isActive(false)` in click handler. That will be handled by default action after `return true`.

Comment: @Dandy Ah yes, true that. Changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two bindings. The status will change when you check the box. All you need is a subscription to the observable to notice that. (The writable computed solution is about the same, but a bit more complicated than necessary.)

```js
var Vm = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.isActive = ko.observable(false);
  self.isActive.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (newValue) alert("Checked");
    else alert("Unchecked");
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isActive" /> Check me!
</label>
```